# Do deletions within the grace period count towards one's personal statistics?

Tags: support, statistics, grace-period, self-delete

If I post a question or an answer and then self-delete it within the **5-minute grace period**, will the deleted post be counted into my statistics (like the "Curious" badge)?

Comment: Makes a ton of sense to wait that 5 minutes, and think before you hit that "Post your answer" button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no 5-minute grace period for deleting a question, so yes it will affect your stats towards the badges.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that it would then feed into the question ban algorithm too?

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes, it would